# Making the criteria in a SUMIF function relative to the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

[Here is a simplified version of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nz4g.png)

[Here is the formula I am entering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qan6N.png)

In D22 I need to enter the same SUMIF formula but the criteria is `ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1)'. How can I create this macro? I have close to 570 rows and data similar and need to condense the dates into just one.

Thanks

I expect the macro to be able to input the sumif formula referencing the range as column $C, the criteria as `$ActiveCell.Offset$(-1,-1)` and the sum range as the column of the active cell so D but not locked as the sum range will change.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the exact VBA you're using?

Comment: Hi BigBen, do the photos help?

Answer (score 1):

Declare and set `Range` variables to the various ranges you require, then build the formula from those variables `.Address` properties.  Use the various parameters of `Address` to set the required Absolute/Relative addressing and External references

```
Sub EnterSum()
    Dim rCritera As Range
    Dim rCriteriaRange As Range
    Dim rSum As Range
    Dim rFormula As Range


    Set rCriteriaRange = ActiveSheet.Columns(3)
    Set rCritera = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1)
    Set rSum = ActiveCell.EntireColumn

    Set rFormula = ActiveCell 'Q doesn't specify this cell, so adjust as needed

    rFormula.Formula = "=SumIf(" & rCriteriaRange.Address(1, 1) & "," & rCritera.Address(1, 1) & "," & rSum.Address(0, 0) & ")"

End Sub
```

Example: if ActiveCell is `D5`  then result is `=SUMIF($C:$C,$C$4,D:D)`

Comment: Thanks chris neilsen, does the photos help? Would it be the same code? I tried entering what you provided but it didnt seem to work

Comment: @kays23 _it didnt seem to work_ is of no use as an error description.  _What_ didn't work? _What actually happened?  If you select cell `D12` and run the macro, you will get exactly the result in your image.

Comment: I copied and pasted your VBA code and changed the active cell to ActiveCell.Select. This resulted in a run error and 'object required' message with 'Set rFormula = ActiveCell' line highlited. Whats the solution for this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @key23 _whats the solution_? Don't do that - copy the code as is. Adding `.Select`  is not required, and obviously harmful

Comment: chris neilsen thank you so much mate! Really Appreciate it.

Comment: @kays23 Glad to help.  Since you are new, I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)